# why is margin not applying without overflow:auto

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to create a view page with label and text next to each other. Now without mentioning overflow auto the margins don't get accounted. Why??

This is my css & html.

```css
.dl-horizontal {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /*overflow:auto*/
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    line-height: 25px;
}


.action-wrap{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Name:</dt>          <dd>My Name</dd>
    <dt>Description:</dt>   <dd>Lorem ipsuem</dd>
    <dt>Group:</dt>         <dd></dd>
</dl>
<div class="action-wrap ng-scope">
     <button class="button cancel" >Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I personally face this problem several times and my quick fix is overflow:auto. Want to know  if it's ok to use it or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: because of [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found a better way, forget what I said below. Just add display: table; to the .dl-horizontal selector. Now the red border (for visual purposes) is the same for each.

It appears that if there is nothing in the dd tag, it won't push the line down. Incidentally, padding-bottom: 20px works, but if you don't want to do that, you might have to put a   (non-breaking space) in the dd field. That seems to work as well. CSS has so many quirks :)

```css
.dl-horizontal {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: table;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 160px;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    line-height: 25px;
}


.action-wrap{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Name:</dt>          <dd>My Name</dd>
    <dt>Description:</dt>   <dd>Lorem ipsuem</dd>
    <dt>Group:</dt>         <dd></dd>
</dl>
<div class="action-wrap ng-scope">
     <button class="button cancel" >Cancel</button>
</div>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Name:</dt>          <dd>My Name</dd>
    <dt>Description:</dt>   <dd>Lorem ipsuem</dd>
    <dt>Group:</dt>         <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
</dl>
<div class="action-wrap ng-scope">
     <button class="button cancel" >Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically due to Margin collapsing.

The adjoining margins (no non-empty content, padding, or border areas, or clearance separate them) of two or more boxes combine to form a single margin.

One of the way to prevent this by adding float property or overflow:auto to the css to prevent Margin collapse.

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1pw4zwhf/1/

Code:

```
.dl-horizontal {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /* overflow:auto; */
     float:left;
}
```